# Error when trying to update data in sql database c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, syntax-error

i am trying to update data with this:

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE gebruikers SET Naam='" + txtNaam.Text 
    + "', Voornaam='" + txtVoornaam.Text 
    + "', Geboortedatum='" + txtGeboortedatum.Text 
    + "', Email='" + txtEmail.Text 
    + "', Gebruikernaam='" + txtGebruikersnaam.Text 
    + "', Wachtwoord='" + txtWachtwoord.Text 
    + "', Straat='" + txtStraat.Text 
    + "', Huisbus='" + txtHuisbus.Text 
    + "', Postcode='" + txtPostcode.Text 
    + "', Plaats='" + txtPlaats.Text 
    + "', Telenummer='" + txtTelefoonnummer.Text 
    +" WHERE Gebr_id = " + int.Parse(txtID.Text);

executeMyQuery(updateQuery);
```

But I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near "test WHERE Gebr_id = 1' at line 1

does anyone know how i could solve this?

Comment: Read [ask], read the error, share your research. You're missing a single quote ending the telephone number's value. also, use parameterized queries and don't store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: You should not post here print screen image but rather type error text here. Btw your code is almost academic example of sql injection vulnerability :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a single quotation missed (') before the where part. Try this:

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE gebruikers SET Naam='" + txtNaam.Text +
  "', Voornaam='" + txtVoornaam.Text + "', Geboortedatum='" +
  txtGeboortedatum.Text + "', Email='" + txtEmail.Text +
  "', Gebruikernaam='" + txtGebruikersnaam.Text + "', Wachtwoord='" +
  txtWachtwoord.Text + "', Straat='" + txtStraat.Text +
  "', Huisbus='" + txtHuisbus.Text + "', Postcode='" + txtPostcode.Text +
  "', Plaats='" + txtPlaats.Text + "', Telenummer='" +
  txtTelefoonnummer.Text + "' WHERE Gebr_id = " + int.Parse(txtID.Text);
executeMyQuery(updateQuery);
```